# Deciding Which Class to Return in Factory

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory

I'm  creating  a `Product`  abstract  class,  which  is supposed  to  be
subclassed  according  to  the   product  category  (each  category  has
different internal  logic but same interface,  hence I chose to  go with
abstraction model).  However, I want the  user to call a  factory method
which decides  what subclass to  return automatically. First, is  it bad
practice to include this factory method in the abstract class itself?

```
abstract class Product
{
    abstract public function getDescription();
    abstract public function getValue();

    public static function
    createProduct($category)
    {
        return # ...
    }
}
```

How can I decide which subclass to return? Of course I could do a
`switch-case`:

```
switch($category) {
    case PROD_BOOK:
        return new Book();
        break;
    case PROD_FOOD:
        return new Food();
        break;
}
```

But this kind of hard codes the  classes. When adding a new product, I'd
have to  add the new  constant for the  category and modify  the factory
logic. I'd like  to keep the factory  logic intact. Is there  any way to
make a table of category keys and class references as values? So I could
do something like:

```
return new ($classes[$category])();
```

Then  I  just need  to  update  the  `$classes`  array when  adding  new
products.

Comment: Yes, `return new $classes[$category];` assuming `$classes[$category]` contains a classname registered in autoloader.

Comment: It'll work fine - but you probably want a `class_exists()` sanity check in there...

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks, but that was just a guess of mine. I don't really know how to store class references in an array. You say classname, but you mean like just a string? Would that play well with namespaces?

Comment: @CD001 sure, i just tried to keep it minimal for the example. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example how it could be implemented:

```
namespace Whatever;

use Any\Other\Book;
use Namespace\Food;

abstract class Product
{
    protected static $categories = [
        'book' => Book::class;
        'food' => Food::class;
    ];

    abstract public function getDescription();
    abstract public function getValue();

    public static function createProduct($category)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$categories[$category])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("There is no such thing as $category.");
        }
        return new self::$categories[$category];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Zend Framework Factory Interface:

```
  interface FactoryInterface
  {
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null);
  }
```

Where $container has logic to call other registered entities, requestedName is name used when asking for entity from entity manager and optional array options used when custom build logic required.

Then from inside factory you do something like

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
  /** all parameters initialisation goes here **/
  $result = new $requestedName(..$params);
  return $result;
}
```

And get object instance via

```
$myAwesomeFactory = new MyAwesomeFactory();
$book = $myAwesomeFactory($container, Book::class);
$food = $myAwesomeFactory($container, Food::class);
```

You should get an idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm having a hard time understanding how this would apply to avoiding referencing the subclass directly, as in your last example

Comment: well.. I myself found solution with passing classnames the easiest one. Anyway you have to pass something which will identify which class to create ($category) in your example. If you have to pass it you will need to use some kind of map which will connect category with class ($classes from your question) and I guess that's the easiest solution. So I prefer passing classnames which makes factory logic much easier.  btw, map array can be like $arr = [PROD_BOOK=>Book::class, PROD_FOOD=>Food::class]; $obj = new $arr[$category]();

Answer (score 0):

This is an already old and answered thread, but as I was looking for something similar, I post the solution I have found: For such an abstract class factory method, one could also use [get_called_class()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.get-called-class) which would return the name of the sub class on which *createProduct()* was called.

```
<?php
namespace Whatever;

abstract class Product
{   
    public static function createProduct() {
        $class = get_called_class();
        /** @var  $inst Product */
        $inst = new $class();
        return $inst;
    }
}

class Book extends Product
{
}

class Food extends Product
{   
}

$product = Book::createProduct();
var_dump($product);
```

with such approach, there is no need for a map of sub classes in the abstract base class.